# Button in fragment is unclickable via the app / Views in fragment aren't responding

Tags: android, android-fragments

The views in my fragment aren't responding at all, textview.setText(str) Doesn't work, When I'm trying to click a button through the app it does nothing but when using "view.performClick()" the onClick function is being called.

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

private TextView tvA;
private Button btnSync;
public String levelscore;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

  levelscore = getArguments().getString("scoreKey");
  Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), levelscore, 1000).show(); //Outputs score
  tvA = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalScore);
  Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "test1", 1000).show(); //Outputs 'test1'
  btnSync = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sync);
  Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), btnSync.getText().toString() , 1000).show(); //Outputs 'SyncScore'
  btnSync.setOnClickListener(this);
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BtnClickable: "+btnSync.isClickable(), 2500).show(); //Outputs 'BtnClickable: true'
  btnSync.performClick(); //Calls the onClick function
  tvA.setText("Test");  //Does nothing

  if(levelscore != null){
      tvA.setText(levelscore); //Does nothing
  }else{
      tvA.setText("Error!");  //Does nothing
  }


   //Inflate the layout for this fragment



  return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
  }
```

The onClick func:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), levelscore, 1000).show(); //Outputs score (via performClick)
Log.d("SCORE", levelscore); //Shows the score in LogCat (via performClick)
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.sync:
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), levelscore, 1000).show(); //Outputs score (via performClick)
    tvA.setText(levelscore); //Does nothing (even via performClick)
    break;

default:
    break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return inflater.inflate(
      R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);`
```

is the problem

`return view;`

Comment: Thanks alot! Forgot to change the return statement ;\
I'll accept the answer when I'll be able to :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 return inflater.inflate(
      R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

to

```
 return view;
```

because you have already inflated a view in your `view` object so you need to return `view`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you return `return inflater.inflate(
          R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);` from `onCreateView()` - you reinitialize the layout and it ends up with nothing you previously initialized.
Use `return view;` instead